# VideoCapture with " int main(int argc, char **argv) "

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, video-capture

I'm trying to use VideoCapture. a part of my code is below.

when I run my code, I got this :

> Error! Insufficient parameters provided.

How can I use my video with this code. I want to open a stream with VLC.
Or if is there any other way, I'd like to use.

I searched that argv[1] is will be my video file. But I don't know how to show my file and how to define my file to this code.

Comment: Have a read through this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/command-line-arguments-in-c-cpp/

Comment: I'm not using Linux sir.

Comment: @NathanOliver I use Windows

Comment: When you execute your program you need to pass 1 command line argument. That is the file name  of your video.

Comment: @NathanOliver and in your link, there is " int argc,char* argv[]" . But my code is like " int main(int argc, char **argv) "

Comment: Windows is the same as linux as far as command line arguments.

Comment: @drescherjm I don't know how to show my video this code. how can I show?

Comment: `char* argv[]` and `char **argv` is basically the same thing.

Comment: The difference in the main signatures is unimportant.

Comment: @NathanOliver But the link didn't help me :(

Comment: @drescherjm I have a video. I want the videocapture show it. argv[1]

Comment: When you run your program from `cmd.exe` next to the name of the executable you provide the path of the video file. make sure there is a space between the two

Comment: @drescherjm like this: " ./a.out c:/video.mpg " ?

Comment: Is your program's executable `a.out`? Did you change directory to the folder containing your program's executable?

Comment: @drescherjm no. it's parser.exe.

Comment: @drescherjm so like this  " parser.exe c:/video.mpg " ?

Comment: should the cmd be in the path of executable? @drescherjm

Comment: Then `parser c:/video.mpg` would be what you type. If you are in the folder containing parser.exe

Comment: @drescherjm where is ".exe" ?

Comment: ***should the cmd be in the path of executable?*** Yes you need to use the cd command in cmd.exe to fix that.

Comment: ***where is ".exe" ?*** Only you can answer that.

Comment: @drescherjm wait I'll try if it won't work, we should fix it. Because my teacher will piss off me if I won't do it.

Comment: also @NathanOliver come here

Comment: This may help: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-command-prompt-introduction/

Comment: Also if you are using an IDE. It should have a way to pass command line arguments to your program when executing it in the debugger.

Comment: @drescherjm I can read the video, but now There is another error

Comment: @opencv_world343.pdb not loaded. it's the error.

Comment: @drescherjm     `matcher_->match(descriptors_object, descriptors_scene, matches)`
this line gives the error. https://github.com/johnalthom13/VideoMosaicking/blob/master/Stitcher.cpp

Comment: ***@opencv_world343.pdb not loaded. it's the error.*** That is just a warning. If you don't have the debug symbols for opencv installed you can't see the inner details of this library when debugging your application. I would say this is likely unimportant to you so you can ignore the warning.

Comment: Where do you see this error message exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help future users, I'd make some changes:

Was:

```
LOG_DEBUG("Error! Insufficient parameters provided.");
```

Is:

```
std::string program(argv[0]);
LOG_DEBUG("Error! Insufficient parameters provided.");
LOG_DEBUG("Please provide a command line argument.");
LOG_DEBUG("Example:  " << program << " VIDEO_FILE_NAME");
```

Explanation:

On the command line, when the program is invoked, the arguments from the command line are copied in the array of strings held by `argv`.   `argv[0]` is the first argument and it is the filename of the program itself.   Put another way, `argv[i]` for `0 <= i < argc` are populated in the array of strings `argv` from the command line.  If you renamed the program executable file, `argv[0]` would be different the next time you ran the program.

The array `argv` is indexed from `0` to `argc-1`.   When `main` is invoked this array of strings and argc are set.  It's up to the software to decide what to do.  In this case your application tests `argc` and finds that if no argument is provided (ie., argc < 2) then the one user argument provided by the user is not present, report the error and return.

Incidentally, there's yet another form of `main` you can use:

`int main(int argc, char** argv, char** envp)`

`argc` = number of arguments.
`argv` = array of argument strings
`envp` = array of environment variable name=value pairs

So beyond simple command line argument passing, one could choose to write the `main` function to grab the environment variables (not shell variables) and decide nuanced action based on that.   Options abound.

But for the time being, your code would be helpful if it reported why there is an error and the suggestions provided seem to do that.

Good luck.